# Distro that is easy to remaster

Tags: linux-distribution

I would like recommendations for an easy to remaster distro. It has to run from a CD and will only run a small web application (client-side; only JavaScript) and print pages. So:

- Has to be a Live CD;
- Easy to remaster/customise;
- A modern web browser;
- Full printer support;
- No network (or disabled by default, in case person has a network printer);
- Any window manager will do, but a simple one is a preferrable (OpenBox or similar);
- As small as possible (although no limit is imposed).

Comment: Take a look at http://www.tuxradar.com/content/build-your-own-linux-distribution-easy-way as it gives a great write-up on some of the choices.

Comment: I read that before. It looks very outdated. Arch and LFS can't be called easy distros and SUSE Studio seems to be little customisable. From what I've searched, Slitaz is the most reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

- The Ubuntu Customisation Kit - `sudo apt-get install uck`
- Linux from Scratch - http://linuxfromscratch.org/livecd
- SUSE Studio - http://susestudio.com/

Certainly the last one allows you to create live CD's and choose what packages you want. Though I don't seem to be able to connect to it right now.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [TinyCore Linux](http://tinycorelinux.net/) which is *tiny* and very easy to remaster.

I can also recommend [Alpine Linux](http://alpinelinux.org/) which is a bit more difficult to remaster, but it also has a small footprint and can run as a LiveCD.

If you're doing this for business purposes, and not too sure where to start, [my company](https://jidoteki.com) specializes in just that - we currently use TinyCore behind the scenes.